# Как из textbox по нажатию enter содержимое добавлять в список и снова обнулить строку?

Tags: c#, list, textbox, key

Пробовал делать такими вариантами, но программа вообще не реагирует на нажатие Enter. Может, в свойствах где-то нужно поставить над чем-то true?

```
private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            orderW = new List<int>();
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {                
                    orderW.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
                    textBox3.Text = "";
            }  
        }

private void textBox4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        stockW = new List<int>();
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {               
                stockW.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
                textBox4.Text = "";
        } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, проблема была в том, что не создавалась подписка. Т.к. в форме при нажатии по энтеру на tb у меня появлялась функция TextChange. Функции же KeyDown и KeyPress я прописывала вручную, соответственно форма о них и не знала. Необходимо было в Form1Designer прописать подписку к tb, но безопаснее в свойствах tb в событиях добавить нужное.

Answer (score 1):

Не пойму, что у вас не работает. 
Делаю форму

```
class F : Form
{
    public F()
    {
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.KeyDown += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter");
            }
        };
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Запускаю

```
void Main()
{
    new F().ShowDialog();
}
```

Получаю

[image: Результат]

Comment: Оказывается, проблема была в том, что не создавалась привязка. Т.к. в форме при нажатии по энтеру на tb у меня появлялась функция TextChange. Функции же KeyDown и KeyPress я прописывала вручную, соответственно форма о них и не знала. Необходимо было в Form1Designer прописать привязку к tb, но безопаснее в свойствах tb в событиях добавить нужное.

Comment: Если пользуетесь дизайнером, то да. Только не привязка, а подписка на событие. Ну, из кода, что вы привели, это было не понять. Но спасибо, что отписали. Думаю, вам можно ваш комментарий добавить как ответ и отметить ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает, дружище

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
```

[image]